# Remove all items from list of strings that exist in 2nd list of strings

Tags: java

I'm going to perform some basic NLP on a series of PDFs and I'd like to remove so-called 'stop words' from the PDFs before I output the word list to a CSV. I create an ArrayList of the stop words as well as the words in the PDF and attempt to use removeAll. I get an unhelpful error - `Exception in thread main` on the removeAll line.

```
public class ReadingText {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  String stopList = "i,me,my,...";
  
  String[] stopList1 = stopList.split(",");
  List<String> stopList2 = Arrays.asList(stopList1);
  
  File file = new File("C:/Users/Documents/Walmart_2020_Annual_Report.pdf");
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
  PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
  String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
  text = text.replace(",", "");
  text = text.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
  text = text.replace(" ", ",");
  
  String[] text2 = text.split(",");
  
  List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(text2);
  
  wordList.removeAll(stopList2);
  
  System.out.println(wordList.size());
```

}
}

Comment: All you got was "Exception in thread main"? Not a specific exception, or an included error message?

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` returns an [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) list, which throws an exception if you try to alter its size.

To make a mutable list from it:

```
wordList = new ArrayList<>(wordList);
```

Comment: Well, sort of.  You can't add to or remove from it but you can change it (it will sort just fine).